# Categorizing on various levels Rails 4 records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a collection of `incoming packages`, that have both a certain `:product` and a certain `supplier`

To categorize it in an accordion, either by supplier or by product, I found this way that is quite DB-speed efficient:

**Controller**

```
def by_supplier
    @incomings = ::Incoming::Product.all
    @suppliers = @incomings.group_by(&:supplier)
end

def by_product
    @incomings = ::Incoming::Product.all
    @products = @incomings.group_by(&:product)
end
```

**Views by supplier**

```
<% @suppliers.each_pair do |supplier, incomings| %>
    <h4 class="box-title">Supplier: <%= supplier.name %></h4>
    </div>
        <%= render "table", data: incomings %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Views by product**

```
<% @products.each_pair do |product, incomings| %>
    <h4 class="box-title">Product: <%= product.name %></h4>
    </div>
        <%= render "table", data: incomings %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me data like this, for instance for suppliers:

> #### Supplier: Supplier A
>
> - Incoming A
> - Incoming D
> - Incoming F
>
> #### Supplier: Supplier B
>
> - Incoming B
> - Incoming C
> - Incoming E
>
> #### Supplier: Supplier C
>
> - Incoming H
> - Incoming J

But now I would like to categorize on 2 levels. For instance this:

> ### Supplier: Supplier A
>
> - #### Product: Product 1
>
>   - Incoming A
>   - Incoming D
> - #### Product: Product 2
>
>   - Incoming F
>
> ### Supplier: Supplier B
>
> - #### Product: Product 1
>
>   - Incoming B
> - #### Product: Product 3
>
>   - Incoming C
>   - Incoming E
>
> ### Supplier: Supplier C
>
> - #### Product: Product 1
>
>   - Incoming H
> - #### Product: Product 4
>
>   - Incoming J

How could I achieve this, in a DB-efficient manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by is just a ruby method, you can do that again.

```
<% @suppliers.each_pair do |supplier, incomings| %>
    <h4 class="box-title">Supplier: <%= supplier.name %></h4>
    <div>
      <% incomings.group_by(&:product).each_pair do |product, product_incomings| %>
        <h4 class="box-title">Product: <%= product.name %></h4>
        <div>
          <%= render "table", data: product_incomings %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then just do the same, but group by supplier on products.

Comment: Thanks! Simpler than I thought. I should have thought it by myself :)